# "PermissionError" thrown when typing "exit()" to leave the Python interpreter

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, sudo

When I enter the python interpreter as a regular user with `python`. I see this:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I can immediately type `exit()` and this happens:

```
>>> exit()
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I think it may be related to the fact that running `sudo python3` gives:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>>
```

This looks to be a different python 3.5 install.

If this is the issue I would like to have my anaconda python install run when I type `sudo python3`. How do I do this?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the two issues you describe (getting an exception when exiting, and getting a different interpreter when running with sudo) are related. For the latter, I'm sure it's a path issue. Try running `which python3` and `sudo which python3` to see where the different interpreters you're running are located. You might be able to call `sudo` with some options that tell it not to change your path around (though whether that's necessarily a good idea is another question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having googled the error message, I found this issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue19891

It seems that the problem often has to do with the current user not having a home directory (which I think is logical for a user called python) or not having the proper permissions on their home directory, but the issue is still open.

Comment: It's probably safe to just leave isn't it?

Comment: Based on the discussion over at python.org, it really looks like an error message that can safely be ignored. I personally would, at any rate. ^^'

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue on python3.4/3.5 . I went back and changed ownership of ~/.python_history to my current user and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the owner of `~/.python_history` from `root` to `my_user_account` solved the problem.